Clear previous value selected PowerBI slicer on change from another slicer
I've 3 slicer in powerbi for referenceId, lower version, higher version.
On selecting reference id I see some versions value available in other two slicer. I've un linked the versions slicer from reference id slicer to see the entire list of values available in referenceid.
All these 3 slicers are single select only.
If I select one reference id and select say version 5 in higher version and then change the selection in reference id to a reference id which doesn't have version 5 then Selection on versions slicer is not removing it. It should auto select the first value available in the slicer and remove the previous selection.

There is a workaround. Assuming you have a slicer with 2-3 options (slicer 1) that filters options on Slicer 2. Create and format Slicer 1 as you want it to look... maybe add padding to separate options... then generate a blank button for each option on Slicer 1, set to transparent, (i like to do on hover actions like border), and place button over each option. Generate a bookmark for each state that you want to see with selection on Slicer 2 (you can do any option), then assigned the bookmark to the respective buttons. And that's it! When the user "thinks" they are clicking the option on the slicer, they are really clicking the button and calling for the bookmark which will "reset" the second slicer really.
For a more advanced feel, play with hiding the buttons of the slicer option selected, so that only the other options are "really" available.
